# Do import statements in Swift have an associated cost?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Reading the String Manifesto, I saw [a paragraph](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md#batteries-included) about avoiding the `Foundation` import when not necessary.

Why is this a concern to the Swift team? Apart from aesthetics and code tidiness, do imports come with a cost?

Could importing unnecessary frameworks impact performance, memory usage, packaged app size or build time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [page](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md#batteries-included) you reference is just saying that they'd like to see more String methods built directly into Swift. Currently some tasks like case-sensitive string comparison require importing Foundation.

Ok I'm going to give the rest of your question a shot. The answer is it depends on what you are importing.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031017/7245977):

> Since Xcode 5, there is a new feature introducing precompiled sources database. Xcode 5 basically compiles all the required frameworks just once, saves builds in the database and that already compiled pieces uses while compiling your code

Also looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165938/how-to-avoid-importing-the-same-framework-on-every-swift-file):

We see that importing `UIKit` in every file that uses it is necessary. If the above solution is correct than regardless of how many times `UIKit` or `Foundation` is imported it is only compiled once. Thus importing a standard library more than once as no affect on compile time.

However, importing something for the first time would affect compile time because that Library now needs to be compiled when it previously was not needed.

Example if I have to import Foundation in a small Swift program the compile time will be slowed down. When it comes to iOS apps it's basically impossible to not import UIKit which also imports Foundation so I don't think this is worth worrying about since every app will have to compile these libraries as well.

Additionally, we need to look at imports that result from things like [Cocoa Pods](https://cocoapods.org/) and [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage):

Looking at [this repo](https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times#third-party-dependencies):

> There are two ways you can embed third-party dependencies in your projects:
>
> **as a source that gets compiled each time you perform a clean build of your project** (examples: CocoaPods, git submodules, copy-pasted code, internal libraries in subprojects that the app target depends on)
>   **as a prebuilt framework/library** (examples: Carthage, static library distributed by a vendor that doesn’t want to provide the source code)
>   *CocoaPods being the most popular dependency manager for iOS by design leads to longer compile times, as the source code of 3rd-party libraries in most cases gets compiled each time you perform a clean build*. In general you shouldn’t have to do that often but in reality, you do (e.g. because of switching branches, Xcode bugs, etc.).
>
> **Carthage, even though it’s harder to use, is a better choice if you care about build times.** You build external dependencies only when you change something in the dependency list (add a new framework, update a framework to a newer version, etc.). That may take 5 or 15 minutes to complete but you do it a lot less often than building code embedded with CocoaPods.

Looking at [this blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-imports):

We see that there are more precise imports that can be used if one is concerned about compile time. Such as `import UIKit.UITableViewController`

> As far as performance and binary size goes, **any unused symbols are already optimized out of the final binary by the Swift compiler. If there’s no reference to it at compile time then it’s removed, meaning that importing a framework but not using particular parts of it shouldn’t have any negative implications.**

[Another blog](https://blog.automatic.com/how-we-cut-our-ios-apps-launch-time-in-half-with-this-one-cool-trick-7aca2011e2ea) states:

> In this [WWDC 2016 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/), Apple suggests replacing dynamic frameworks with static archives to mitigate this. To take this approach, we rebuilt as many of our dynamic frameworks as possible statically and then merged them into a single monolithic dynamic framework named AutomaticCore.
>
> The difference was dramatic: **our app’s launch time was cut in half.**

**TLDR:** It's not worth worrying about importing standard things like Foundation or UIKit they are only compiled once and just about every app uses them so any performance decrease is shared. However, if you are importing third party Frameworks you might want to use a static archive to help with compile time.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer and references. In short it would seem that importing frameworks in a file do not affect the app at runtime, but may of course impact build times if used improperly.

Comment: In your TLDR you said "help with compile time" but above that you stated Apple was referring to launch time that was cut in half. Is that a typo? Also, TLDR should be placed at the top - otherwise I already read everything when I see it.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no doubt that importing frameworks increases the raw file size of your app, they are generally very well compressed. And if you need the framework, you have no choice but to import it. Practically, however, file size is not an issue when it comes to frameworks--relatively large ones, like Mapbox, can be included at the cost of just a few MB to your end product. And it's a shared cost by all apps so it's a wash.

Framework code is also stored in shared libraries, not in your executable, which is a very important distinction. Regardless of which Apple platform you're programming for, read Apple's OS X documentation on frameworks because the general concepts are the same. In it, it briefly talks about the relationship between framework inclusion and performance:

> If you are worried that including a master header file may cause your
>   program to bloat, don’t worry. Because OS X interfaces are implemented
>   using frameworks, the code for those interfaces resides in a dynamic
>   shared library and not in your executable. In addition, only the code
>   used by your program is ever loaded into memory at runtime, so your
>   in-memory footprint similarly stays small.
>
> As for including a large number of header files during compilation,
>   once again, don’t worry. Xcode provides a precompiled header facility
>   to speed up compile times. By compiling all the framework headers at
>   once, there is no need to recompile the headers unless you add a new
>   framework. In the meantime, you can use any interface from the
>   included frameworks with little or no performance penalty.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html

That said, don't import frameworks that are already imported by default from "umbrella" frameworks. For example, importing `UIKit` automatically imports `Foundation` so don't import both. Does this really make a difference? No, but caring about the details, even the unimportant ones, is what will snowball someone into a programmer other people want to hire and work with. I can't tell you how many programmers I've collaborated with in the past who had the "who cares" attitude about things like this. It's no surprise their code was always the sloppiest and they're the ones always out of work.

Comment: Interesting points. However I now realize my question wasn't as clear as I first thought. When I said "importing unnecessary frameworks" I meant using the `import` statement on libraries not used in that specific file, such as using `import UIKit` in a file that doesn't have any references to any UIKit API.

Comment: I understand your question now. Importing frameworks into specific files is a matter of encapsulation because all that `import` does is expose a source file to a specific module (so that it can be used). Imagine if you made all of your properties global, thereby exposing them to all of the app's other objects. Your app would have terrible encapsulation and compile time (among other things) would suffer. The Runtime environment, however, depending on how the app was built, may go relatively unscathed. Encapsulation is a tenet of OOP and one should never import a library that is never used.